# What can we say about if $\operatorname{Adj}(A)$ is equals to matrix $A$?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

What can we say about the determinant of $A$ if $\operatorname{Adj}(A)$ is equals to matrix $A$ ?

Comment: What do you know about $\operatorname{Adj}(A)$ in the first place? Odds are, the answer to your problem lies in there somewhere.

Comment: HINT: if $\det A \neq 0$, then $Adj (A) =(\det A) A^{-1}$

Comment: @Crostul You can rearrange that to work for singular matrices as well.

Comment: $A$ could be a null matrix or  $\\pm I$ mayrix.

Comment: If $Adj(A)=A$ & $det(A)\ne0 $ then $Adj(A)\cdot A=det(A)I_{n\times n}\Rightarrow A^2=det(A)I_{n\times n}$

Comment: can we say that determinant should be 1 ?

Comment: @JohnMars No reason to assume $\det A \neq 0$ in that argument.